# How to Deploying to On Prem Servers(Linux) Using Azure DevOps Deployment Groups

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a deployment group and able to create a agent on my server (linux machine) . Target machine was set. All I need was to create a release pipeline, So I created a release pipeline and select artifacts from build ( I already build that).
For Stage I select empty job and then select “Deployment Group Job”  , Add my deployment group that I created and save the changes.

I select another task i.e “Copy Files” that copy files from artifacts to “/var/www/html” on my server(linux).
After this I run the release and deploy it. It succeed but what is does, that  it copy zip file to the path I provide on my server.

/var/www/html/11.zip
That is not what I want.  I want that it unzip the artifact that was built and deploy code to path I mention so that I can run my application there.

I may be choosing wrong task. But all I need it to run my application from my server. If I need to add some different task , what are those ?

Comment: So unzip the file before you copy it? You can run bash scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I need to add some different task , what are those ?

Since  you need to deploy Unzipped files to the target path, you can directly use the [Extract files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) to replace the Copy file task in Deployment Group.

Here is an example:

[image]

In the **Destination folder** field , you could input the target path.

Then this task will unzip the zip file and send the unzipped  files to the target path.

Comment: Hello @Kevin.Does, the extract files task will unzip only the zip file I got from the build pipeline or does it unzip any file in the destination folder i.e "/var/www/html" location. I only want to extract artifacts I got from the build job?